# Do any versions of Ramayana talk about Mata Sita swallowing Lakshmana up?

Tags: ramayana, sita, lakshmana

I heard from a random source that while coming back from Ayodhya, Mata Sita went to the Sarayu river with Lakshmana so that he can worship that river. Mata Sita asked Lakshamana to bring water from the river, when Lakshmana went to bring water then one demon came out of the river and he was about to swallow Lakshmana. When Mata Sita saw it then she quickly swallowed Lakshmana herself before the demon could do it (to protect Lakshman).

Does any version of Ramayana speak of such a story?

Comment: [This](https://navbharattimes.indiatimes.com/astro/others/why-sita-swallowed-laxman-ji-24098/) news article says it's a folklore (यह घटना लोक कथा पर आधारित है )...but still not sure about all Ramayana versions...